# Ajax not calling alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

im successfuly inserted data to my db with ajax.. but somehow it does not pop up my success alert message. here is a sample of my jquery code.

```
$('button[name="submitmsgd"]').click(function(e){
    var categorysupAr = [];
    var unitsgdAr=[];
    var idsgdAr=[];
    var idsgdlength= $("input[name='idsgd[]']").val().length;
    var namesgdAr= [];
    var namesgdlength= $("input[name='namesgd[]']").val().length;
    var detailsgdAr = [];
    var qtysgdAr = [];
    var pricesgdAr = [];
    var totalsAr = [];
    var datefield= $("input[name='datetime']").val();
    $("select[name='categorysup[]']").each(function(){
        categorysupAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("select[name='unitsgd[]']").each(function(){
        unitsgdAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='idsgd[]']").each(function(){
        idsgdAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='namesgd[]']").each(function(){
        namesgdAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("textarea[name='detailsgd[]']").each(function(){
        detailsgdAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='qtysgd[]']").each(function(){
        qtysgdAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='pricesgd[]']").each(function(){
        pricesgdAr.push(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='totals[]']").each(function(){
        totalsAr.push(this.value);
    });
    if ($.inArray("defaultc", categorysupAr)>-1){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please choose the right category in all fields");

    }
    else if ($.inArray("defaultu", unitsgdAr)>-1){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please choose the right unit in all fields");
    }
    else if ($.inArray("", idsgdAr)>-1||idsgdlength<=2){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert ("ID can't be empty, and must be more than 2 characters in all fields");
    }
    else if ($.inArray("", namesgdAr)>-1||namesgdlength<=2){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert ("Name can't be empty, and must be more than 2 characters");
    }
    else if ($.inArray("", totalsAr)>-1||$.inArray("0", totalsAr)>-1){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert ("Please make sure all quantity and all prices are filled with correct format(Only number allowed)");
    }else{ 
       $.ajax({
           url: "include/insertmsgd.php",
           method: "POST",
           data:{category:categorysupAr, unitsgd:unitsgdAr, idsgd:idsgdAr, namesgd:namesgdAr, detailsgd:detailsgdAr, qtysgd:qtysgdAr, pricesgd:pricesgdAr, totals:totalsAr, datefield:datefield},
           success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
           }
       });
    }
});
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
include "myconfiguration.php";

if (isset($_POST["idsgd"])) {
    $idsgd      = $_POST["idsgd"];
    $category   = $_POST["category"];
    $unitsgd    = $_POST["unitsgd"];
    $namesgd    = $_POST["namesgd"];
    $detailsgd  = $_POST["detailsgd"];
    $qtysgd     = $_POST["qtysgd"];
    $pricesgd   = $_POST["pricesgd"];
    $totals     = $_POST["totals"];
    $date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST["datefield"]));

    for($index=0; $index<count($idsgd); $index++) {
        $idsgd_unstring     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $idsgd[$index]);
        $category_unstring  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $category[$index]);
        $unitsgd_unstring   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $unitsgd[$index]);
        $namesgd_unstring   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $namesgd[$index]);
        $detailsgd_unstring = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $detailsgd[$index]);
        $qtysgd_unstring    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $qtysgd[$index]);
        $pricesgd_unstring  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $pricesgd[$index]);
        $totals_unstring    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $totals[$index]);

        $query= '
        INSERT INTO msgeneralgoods 
        VALUES("'.$idsgd_unstring.'", "'.$category_unstring.'", "'.$unitsgd_unstring.'", "'. $namesgd_unstring.'", 
        "'.$detailsgd_unstring.'", "'.$qtysgd_unstring.'", "'.$pricesgd_unstring.'", "'.$totals_unstring.'", "'.$date.'"); 
        ';
       mysqli_query($conn, $query);
       
    }
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Data Inserted")';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Error")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

i did try this code for my if condition inside my php page

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo 'Data Saved';
} else {
    echo 'Error'
}
```

but still no alert message.... im very new to ajax, can some1 please tell me what did i do wrong here?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: open the developper tool from your browser, see if the ajax is even getting called, you can also see there what your ajax is returning, depending on if you have errer reporting on etc..

Comment: Your running a query in the loop, multiple times. Once you finish the loop you then run the last query ONE MORE TIME in order to see if that single query worked??? That really does not make any sense

Comment: `language="javascript"` was deprecated so long ago. Anyway returning a string containing a piece of html (javascript) is not going to cause that JS to be run, Instead return a status or a message that you then test in the `success` method and run the relevant code based of that status

Comment: Have you watched the process using the browsers builtin debugger? F12 will normally load the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after thorough search in console and googling, i found out that my ajax call was canceled because my save button is

```
button type="submit"
```

so i change it to

```
button type="button"
```

that way i can see my alert pop up..

hope this help to whoever have the same problem as me

Answer (score 0):

add error to the ajax call to return error if there is one

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "include/insertmsgd.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{category:categorysupAr, unitsgd:unitsgdAr, idsgd:idsgdAr, namesgd:namesgdAr, detailsgd:detailsgdAr, qtysgd:qtysgdAr, pricesgd:pricesgdAr, totals:totalsAr, datefield:datefield},
        success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
   });
```

Comment: Thats a debugging suggestion but not really an answer to the question